# Obj exported from blender is split along the UV seams when opened in maya

Tags: uv, export, import

If I export a obj from blender that has UV maps, when the file is imported into maya it is in pieces, its split along the UV seams. For example if I was to import a box with seams along all edges, it would be broken into 6 faces. Does anyone know why this is happening and how i can fix it without merging it all back together in maya?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclick Include Edges in export settings:

[image]